# How to disable and enable itemupdated event office 365 CSOM (RER)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, remote-event-receiver

How to disable/enable `ItemUpdated` event in remote event receiver  in Office 365 using C# CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a special feature to add your item updated event receiver.

When you want to enable item updated event, you can activate the feature.

When you want to disable item updated event, you can deactivate the feature.

Here is a simple demo about activate/deactivate feature via CSOM for your reference:

```
    #region Activate/Deactivate Feature
    /// <summary>
    /// Activate Feature
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="featureId"></param>
    /// <param name="force">true</param>
    /// <param name="featdefScope">
    ///        Parameter FeatureDefinitionScope is used for specifying the feature scope for a feature definition. At the same time the documentation says:
    ///        It must have the value of FeatureDefinitionScope.Site or  FeatureDefinitionScope.Farm
    ///        It basically means that the method FeatureCollection.Add does not accept FeatureDefinitionScope.Web value for featdefScope and therefore feature activation with Web scope is not supported in CSOM.
    ///        In your case, if one of the features is Web scoped, you should specify FeatureDefinitionScope.None
    /// </param>
    public static void ActivateFeature(ClientContext context, Guid featureId, bool force, FeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
    {
            FeatureCollection features = context.Web.Features;
            context.Load(features);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            features.Add(featureId, force, featdefScope);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// deactivate Feature of Web
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="featureId"></param>
    /// <param name="force"></param>
    public static void DeactivateWebFeature(ClientContext context, Guid featureId, bool force)
    {
        FeatureCollection features = context.Web.Features;
        context.Load(features);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        features.Remove(featureId, force);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// deactivate Feature of Site
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="featureId"></param>
    /// <param name="force"></param>
    public static void DeactivateSiteFeature(ClientContext context, Guid featureId, bool force)
    {
        FeatureCollection features = context.Site.Features;
        context.Load(features);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        features.Remove(featureId, force);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    #endregion
```